# javascript popup window as iframe, div,or window always on top on changing links

Tags: javascript, jquery

in web page, is it possible to open 'popup' frame as:
div or iframe or even window, so :
1. the user can see both , the pop window and the 'main' page ?

2. on change link in specific domain, the popped frame will remain always on top
   ( with additional code if needed)
3. the user can see both the frame and the main  a
   and get focus with mouse click on the popped and main
4. possibility to access objects/events from popped and main.
   (in iframe even on different origin)
5. in standard desktop application, we can achieve it, as MDI forms, for example.

   code sample or link will help.

Comment: You probably want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oawofoz7/ (IE 8 and below **won't** like it).

Comment: this example not good enough because I cannot set focus on both 'frames'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```js
$("#simple").dialog(
{ 
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function()
    {
       $("#withIframe").dialog( "moveToTop" );
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
       $("#withIframe").dialog( "moveToTop" );
    }
});
$("#withIframe").dialog(
  { 
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function(ev, ui){
       $('#if').attr('src','http://www.jQuery.com');
       $(this).dialog( "moveToTop" );
    }
  });

$(".link").click(function() {
  $("#simple").dialog('option','modal',$('#isModal').prop('checked')).dialog( "open" );
});

$(".link_iframe").click(function() {
  $("#withIframe").dialog( "open" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<label><input type='checkbox' id='isModal' /> Is Modal? </label>
<a href='#' class='link'>link</a>
<a href='#' class='link_iframe'>link (iframe)</a>

<div id='simple'>
  <h2>
    Simple dialog
  </h2>
</div>

<div id='withIframe'>
  <iframe id='if'  src=''></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: on link on other web page(same domain), how to set that the iframe will be always on top because the link may take the whole page?

Comment: @user3782475 have you notice checkbox isModal? it makes dialog window on top and block whole page from other user events. Modified ansver by adding moveToTop call.

Comment: the moveToTop in the iframe, helped!. is it possible that on click(focus) on simple dialog(that can be <a href> on whole page) the iframe still will be visible ? the iframe will be a chat app.  now, the simple dialog covers the iframe on focus

Comment: @user3782475 added focus event handler.

Comment: yes, it make the work ! , about my question, from iframe src link to other domain than 'simple dialog'(main) how I interact with 'main' objects/events like : onmouse over/click...

Comment: from iframe you cant interact with main page dom or js. Only in other way.

Comment: I took a look, in moveToTop, it actually set the higher z-index to find the highest z-index I need to run on all web page elements ?

Comment: click on <a href for new page, will preserve the iframe dialog, I still can see it's DOM elements ?

Comment: new page is a new page. if it with `target="blank"` it should open new tab or window. There is no relations with iframe.

Comment: you mean the iframe object will be preserve in the DOM, and I can always set it's z-index max value, and be visible in the 'new' web-page

Comment: dialog and iframe in it is a part of current page DOM. Sorry i don't understand you.

Comment: I mean in general application, not your 'demo', that I have 'my iframe' with the new (general) web page